# Send email notification when meet the condition

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, email

I have two post type named ‘post-type-one’ and ‘post-type-two.'
Both post type has exact similar category a,b,c,d,e
I want when a post publish under category ‘a’ on ‘post-type-one' send a email notification to an author under category ‘a’ on ‘post-type-two’.
Can anyone suggest me a plugin (free or premium) to do this? Or do you have any idea how it can be done?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, do you have the email address of the author or you want your code to find it automatically or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to automatically send an email whenever a post of the type `one` is published. This goes into your theme's `functions.php` :

```
<?php 
    function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
        $type = get_post_type($ID);
        if ($type == 'post-type-one'){
            $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
            $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
            $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
            $title = $post->post_title;
            $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
            $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
            $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
            $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
            $message = sprintf ('%s, Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
            $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
            $headers[] = '';
            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
?>
```

You can read and the code and modify the parts that you want, depending on your needs. I could post a more accurate answer if your question was clear. However, the function itself is pretty explanatory.

Comment: Hi Jack Johansson,
i appreciate your answer :) i am trying to make it more clear now.
i have two post type 'health' another 'customer' and two user role 'health' and 'customer' where 'health' user can post a post under 'health' post type and 'customer' user can post a post under 'customer' post type.
Both post type have same category a,b,c,d so i want send a email notification when 'customer' user publish a post under 'customer' post type with category 'a', the email notification will go 'health' user/ author who previously published a post under 'health' post type with 'a' category.

Comment: Does it make more clear than previous details? if not let me know i will try to present it another way :)